# Non-blocking memory write in x86 instructions?

Tags: c, x86, sse, hpc

I am writing some highly optimised code and here is one thing that has bugged me for quite a while, I have a triple-for loop like fellows:

```
 for(int ii = 0; ii < ny; ii++){
     for(int jj = 0; jj < nx; jj++){
        ....some serious calculation....
        for(int kk = 0; kk < CONSTANT; kk++){
            _mm_storeu_ps(&((cells.dir[kk])[ii * nx +jj],result); // Writing result to correct location
        }
     }
 }
```

The cells is just a struct of 9 pointers, each pointing to a large size array. The code is originally written in array of struct(AoS) mode, I manually rewrote the whole thing to use struct of array so I can use SSE to speed it up. But due to the original structure of the code , the code above has to write the result to the correct location in a cache-unfriendly way, If I comment that line out the running time of my whole program can taken down by more than 40%. I am just wondering if there is any non-blocking memory write instruction for x86 that I can take advantage of? Or some other tricks I can play with this memory write? Please do not suggest to change the structure of the loop, it is too time costing.

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: Writes on pretty much every modern non-embedded processor are already non-blocking. They just get pushed onto a queue and are done in the background. That said, there's a limit to the size of that queue before it does become blocking. That said, also be aware of how you use the cachelines.

Comment: @Mysticial I just found out it is more likely because ```_mm_storeu_ps``` is very expensive rather than cache misses here that are slowing down my program. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @dorafmon: Do you need the results to be in those exact memory locations, or are you going to read them back in later for more computations? You might be able to improve performance by writing them in a more cache-friendly way to a temporary buffer. I've done this in the past to some success. But, if those stores are for final results that need to be in that particular order in the output array, you might just be out of luck.

Comment: @JasonR I am on the unlucky situation here

Comment: Can you guarantee that the write location is 16-byte aligned? The aligned store instruction is faster than unaligned, and you could also use the streaming store to avoid the cache.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw I might be able to guarantee it is aligned properly. but what do you mean by avoiding the cache? can you show me some example?

Comment: @dorafmon The streaming instructions provide non-temporal hints which tell the processor "I'm not going to use this again anytime soon, so don't bother putting it in the cache." Since it is not placed in the cache, it won't replace things in the cache you need. You would probably want the `movntps` instruction, which you would write as `_mm_stream_ps(&((cells.dir[kk])[ii * nx +jj],result)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See section 9.11 **Explicit cache control** in Agner Fog's manual [optimizing cpp](http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_cpp.pdf).  Particularly look at Example 9.6b (posted below) on page 99 which shows how to do writes without reading a cache line using the `_mm_stream_pi` intrinsic.  I have not tried it myself yet but it's worth looking into.  This helps when the matrix size is a multiple of of critical stride.  However, the better solution is probably to change your code and use loop tiling (see example 9.5b) but you said you did not want to change the structure of the loop so using `_mm_stream_ps` may be the best option.

```
// From Agner Fog's manual optimizing cpp on page 99
// Example 9.6b
#include "xmmintrin.h" // header for intrinsic functions
// This function stores a double without loading a cache line:
static inline void StoreNTD(double * dest, double const & source) {
    _mm_stream_pi((__m64*)dest, *(__m64*)&source); // MOVNTQ
    _mm_empty(); // EMMS
}
const int SIZE = 512; // number of rows and columns in matrix
// function to transpose and copy matrix
void TransposeCopy(double a[SIZE][SIZE], double b[SIZE][SIZE]) {
    int r, c;
    for (r = 0; r < SIZE; r++) {
        for (c = 0; c < SIZE; c++) {
            StoreNTD(&a[c][r], b[r][c]);
        }
    }
}
```